# How can I tell Tank Auth to not activate users at all?

Tags: php, codeigniter, tankauth

For the CodeIgniter project I'm creating, it is necessary that users get activated manually by an admin after registering.

Currently I'm using Tank Auth (http://www.konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/) for user authentication, and it seems to be missing this particular setting. Is there any chance I just didn't find the setting? If not, how (and *where*) would I start coding that feature myself?

Comment: Are you set on using Tank Auth? Would you consider something else?

Comment: I'd prefer tank auth, seeing as it's already quite ingrained in my app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're interested in a quick hack, I think this would work.

Look in application/config/tank_auth.php and be sure that $config['email_activation'] is set to TRUE.

Then in the application/controllers/auth.php sign_up method look for this line:
$this->_send_email('activate', $data['email'], $data);

Change $data['email'] to the admin's email address. So you end up with something like this:
$this->_send_email('activate', 'admin@example.com', $data);

Then when users sign up, an email will come to the admin with the activation link to activate the user.

Comment: A quick hack is all I need for now :) Thank you very much.

Comment: I have followed the above but in my case by default the user is activated when created